# Outlook dispose application

Tags: c#, winforms, interop

I use Windows Forms and I execute Outlook application using `Interop` Library as:

```
 Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
 Outlook.MailItem mailMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mailMessage.Subject = "test@mail.us";
            mailMessage.HTMLBody = "test";
            mailMessage.Display(true);
```

To execute Outlook I use `mailMessage.Display(true);`, but when I use that I can not use my application anymore, my app just froze up, but when I close Outlook app work again. How can I dispose of outlook as a dependency of the app in order to use my app and outlook at the same time?. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Create a backgroundWorker

Create a backgroundWorker instance by adding it through the Toolbox under components.

## 2. In the Form constructor

Place the newly added backgroundWorker instance in the constructor of the form class:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    outlookWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(outlookWorker_DoWork);
}
```

## 3. RunWorkAsync

Add the RunWorkerAsync method through the backgroundWorker instance in the button_click event for the button that's supposed to open the outlook window:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    outlookWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

## 4. Opening the outlook window

Add the previously written code to instantiate an outlook window to a DoWork event for the backgroundWorker:

```
private void outlookWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mailMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mailMessage.Subject = "test@mail.us";
    mailMessage.HTMLBody = "test";
    mailMessage.Display(true);
}
```

Now you can push any button or perform secondary actions on your form after opening the outlook window.

I hope this has helped you achieve your goal.

## Sources

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1